# How to define MongoDB Schema for Typicode Posts and Users?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I want to seed data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

I defined the mongodb schema for User like

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
  address: {
    street: {
      type: String,
    },
    suite: {
      type: String,
    },
    city: {
      type: String,
    },
    zipcode: {
      type: String,
    },
    geo: {
      lat: {
        type: String,
      },
      lng: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
  },
  website: {
    type: String,
  },
  company: {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    catchPhrase: {
      type: String,
    },
    bs: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

and for Post

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
  },
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

I am seeding data with a seeder function like

```
const importData = async () => {


try {
    await Post.deleteMany();
    await User.deleteMany();

    const createdUsers = await User.insertMany(users);
    console.log("created users", createdUsers);

    const samplePosts = await Post.insertMany(posts);
    console.log("sampleProducts", samplePosts);
    process.exit();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`${error}`.red.inverse);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

However I am getting an error of

> ValidationError: userId: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type number) at path "userId" because of "BSONTypeError"

What does this error mean? And how I can resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "1" (type number) at path "userId" because of "BSONTypeError"
```

This error indicates that we use wrong data type on the script.

The solutions is to change the data type from `Number` to `String`.